# Get the GEBCO 2014 box from latitude and longitute

Tags: mapping, depth

I am trying to get the information from

http://coastal-mapping.eu/

It is a great viewer that shows the depth or altitude of a coordinate and the contour if you select tools and draw a line.

The issue is that it uses a grid system instead of latitude longitude: for instance calling to 28.4066N, 16.3033W which creates the following call:

```
http://wxs-coastal-mapping-eu.aw.atos.net/wms/r/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&QUERY_LAYERS=BODC-GEBCO&LAYERS=BODC-GEBCO&TILED=false&INFO_FORMAT=application%2Fjson&FEATURE_COUNT=1&I=29&J=0&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&CRS=EPSG%3A3035&STYLES=&BBOX=1039062.5%2C1741699.21875%2C1042480.46875%2C1745117.1875' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Host: wxs-coastal-mapping-eu.aw.atos.net' -H 'Origin: http://coastal-mapping.eu' -H 'Referer: http://coastal-mapping.eu/' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0
```

Where creates an special BBOX based on the GEBCO system.

```
BBOX=1039062.5,1741699.21875,1042480.46875,1745117.1875
```

Is there a way to convert latitude, longitude into that BBOX system?

Comment: As an aside, GEBCO data is free for public use - http://www.gebco.net

Comment: Yes I have asked a box of data from here https://www.bodc.ac.uk, but would be great an online service that can get the grid numbers from latitude and longitude